# R: Getting rows from specific columns

Tags: r

In R, say you have a named numeric such as:

```
3777 3727 3421 2373 3259  512 3174 3456 3536  805 
   4    4    8    9    2    2    6    4    6    6
```

The values on the top are rownames from a larger matrix, and the values below it are the column of data I want from that row.

So, I want from dataframe (or matrix) row with name 3777, col 4's value. and so on.

What is the easiest way to do this?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use row index instead of row names? If so, you don't need a loop:

```
a <- rnorm(10000)
M <- matrix(a,nrow=100)
c1 <- c(1,3,4,5,9) #3777 3727 3421 2373 3259  512 3174 3456 3536  805
c2 <- c(3,8,10,11,23)  #   4    4    8    9    2    2    6    4    6    6
M[cbind(c1,c2)]
# [1] -0.8216866  0.5427404  0.4462874 -0.6547175 -1.6598367
```

Comment: Why are you doing `t(rbind())` and not just `cbind()`? Also, sticking with the presence of `row.names` you could just use `M[cbind(match(names(myNamedNum), rownames(M)), myNamedNum)]`.

Comment: `cbind()`! Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is:

```
myMatrix #any matrix

myNamedNum #from above example

for (i in 1:length(myNamedNum)){

    myMatrix[names(myNamedNum[i]),as.numeric(myNamedNum[i])]
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop here. You can just use matrix indexing. Create a matrix to subset from where the first column is the rows you want, and the second is the columns you want. Since you are dealing with `rownames`, you can use `match` to get the position of the row. A complete example would be: `M[cbind(match(names(myNamedNum), rownames(M)), myNamedNum)]`